# Counting the number of lowercase, uppercase, and numbers from a string entered by a user

Tags: c++

```
import<string>
import<iostream>

bool isNumber(char ch) {
    //this function will determine if a character is a number.
    //this allows the function to use an ASCLL value
    if (int i = ch >= '0' && ch <= '9') {
        //If character found is anything from 0-9 operation will return the condition true.
        return true;
    }//ends the statement
    else {
        //else return the condition false
        return false;
    }//ends the statement
}//ends the function

bool isUpperCase(char ch) {
    //this function will determine if a character is upper case.
    //this allows the function to use an ASCLL value
    if (int i = ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z') {
        //If character found is anything from A-Z operation will return the condition true.
        return true;
    }//ends the statement
    else {
        return false;
        //else return the condition false
    }//ends the statement
}//ends the function


bool isLowerCase(char ch) {
    //this function will determine if a character is lower case.
    //this allows the function to use an ASCLL value
    if (int i = ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z') {
        //If character found is anything from a-z operation will return the condition true.
        return true;
    }//ends the statement
    else {
        return false;
        //else return the condition false
    }//ends the statement

}//ends the function

void processData(char text[], int size) {

    int upperCase = 0;
    int lowerCase = 0;
    int numbers = 0;
    int i;
    text[size];
    for (i = 0; i <= text[size]; i++) {

        if (isNumber(text[i]) == true) {
            numbers++;
        }
        else if (isUpperCase(text[i]) == true) {
            upperCase++;
        }
        else if (isUpperCase(text[i]) == true) {
            lowerCase++;
        }

    }
    std::cout << "There are " << upperCase << " uppercase letters in this string." << std::endl;
    std::cout << "There are " << lowerCase << " lowercase letters in this string." <<std::endl;
    std::cout << "There are " << numbers << " numbers in this string." << std::endl;

}

int main()
{

    std::cout << "Enter some text: ";
    std::string s;
    std::getline(std::cin, s);

    int size = sizeof(s);
    char text[sizeof(s)];


    processData(text, size);

    return 0;
}
```

I am trying to create a program that will count the number of numbers, lowercase letters and uppercase letters.  But my code keeps returning all the values at 0.  I know my boolean functions are correct because they worked when I counted the numbers in lowercase letters and uppercase letters in a file. Can some please give some insight on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: `i <= text[size]` is wrong. use `i < size` instead

Comment: I changed that and it is still not working.

Comment: `int size = sizeof(s); char text[sizeof(s)];` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: `import<string>` and `import<iostream>` ... are you using some kind of modules?

Comment: Prefer to write your checking functions using this style instead: `bool isUpperCase(char ch) { return ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z'; }` - It's much easier to read and doesn't involve an unnecessary variable and an unnecessary `if`.

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel. [`std::isdigit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isdigit), [`std::isupper`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isupper), and [`std::islower`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/islower) do this for you, and don't make assumptions about the character encoding. There are character encodings that have other characters in the middle of the lowercase letters and in the middle of the uppercase letters.

Answer (score 2):

I saw two bugs right away, but I don't know if there are more because I have not tried to run your code.

1. Since `s` is a `string` instead of an array, it's invalid to use `sizeof` on it.  (Try printing out `sizeof(s)` if you don't believe me.)  Use `s.length()` to get the length of the string instead.
2. You never actually populated your `text` array with any data, so it is uninitialized when you pass it to `processData`.  Instead of making the `text` array, try this:

   ```cpp
   processData(s.c_ptr(), s.length());
   ```

   But to avoid warnings, you probably need to change `processData` so its first argument is const, like this: `const char * text`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;


//Not to type std:: over and over again.
bool isNumber(char ch) {
    //this function will determine if a character is a number.
    if (int i = ch >= '0' && ch <= '9') {
        //If character found is anything from 0-9 operation will return the condition true.
        return true;
    }//ends the statement
    else {
        //else return the condition false
        return false;
    }//ends the statement
}//ends the function

bool isUpperCase(char ch) {
    //this function will determine if a character is upper case.
    if (int i = ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z') {
        //If character found is anything from A-Z operation will return the condition true.
        return true;
    }//ends the statement
    else {
        return false;
        //else return the condition false
    }//ends the statement
}//ends the function


bool isLowerCase(char ch) {
    //this function will determine if a character is lower case.
    if (int i = ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z') {
        //If character found is anything from a-z operation will return the condition true.
        return true;
    }//ends the statement
    else {
        return false;
        //else return the condition false
    }//ends the statement

}//ends the function

void processData(char text[], int size) {
    int specialCharacter = 0;
    int upperCase = 0;
    int lowerCase = 0;
    int numbers = 0;
    int i;
    
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    
        if (isNumber(text[i]) == true) {
            numbers++;
        }
        else if (isUpperCase(text[i]) == true) {
            upperCase++;
        }
        else if (isLowerCase(text[i]) == true) {
            lowerCase++;
        }
        
    }
    cout << "There are " << upperCase << " uppercase letters in this string." << endl;
    cout << "There are " << lowerCase << " lowercase letters in this string." <<endl;
    cout << "There are " << numbers << " numbers in this string." << endl;
}//ends the prosses Data function

int main()
{   
    
    cout << "Enter some text: ";
    //Outputs enter some text onto the console.
    string str;
    //initiates the string variable name to str
    getline(cin, str);
    //gets the whole line of input and stores it in the string variable
    int size = sizeof(str);
    //sets the integer size to be the size of the string
    char text[sizeof(str)];
    // sets the character text array to set the number of characters equal to the size of the string
    str.copy(text, size);
    //converts the string into a character array
    processData(text, size);
    //calls the processData function 
    return 0;
    //returns the main function at 0.
}//ends the main function
```

I found the problem I forgot to convert the string input to an array of characters. `str.copy(text, size);` was all that was needed to fix the code.

Comment: No - this will lead to future angst. `int size = sizeof(str);` is utterly wrong and so is `char text[sizeof(str)];`.because `sizeof(str)` is a _constant expression_ - It will _always_ be the same size when you run the program - no matter how long the actual string is. You should do what David Grayson suggested in the other answer.